# How to generate session in MPGS (Mastercard Payment Gateway Services)

Tags: javascript, html

i want to integrate MPGS payment in my Nodejs application but i have a problem. I create an account in https://developer.mastercard.com/ (i don't know this the correct website to use or not I'm beginner) i found this code in the internet that embed the form of the payment in my application
this is the code

```
<script src="https://test-gateway.mastercard.com/static/checkout/checkout.min.js" data-error="errorCallback"
    data-cancel="cancelCallback"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function errorCallback(error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
    function cancelCallback() {
        console.log('Payment cancelled');
    }
    Checkout.configure({
        merchant: 'X',
        order: {
            amount: function () {
                return 100;
            },
            currency: 'USD',
            description: 'Subscription Member',
            id: '1000',
        },
        interaction: {
            merchant: {
                name: 'Hsenid Mobile',
                address: {
                    line1: '200 Sample St',
                    line2: '1234 Example Town'
                }
            }
        },
        session: {
            id: "X"
        }
    });
</script>
```

the problem was i can't know what is the merchant ID to generate the session id where i can find it i also read the documentation [here](https://eu-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/apiDocumentation/rest-json/version/latest/operation/Hosted%20Checkout%3a%20Initiate%20Checkout.html?locale=en_US) but i don't understand how to find the merchant ID

```
<script src="https://test-gateway.mastercard.com/static/checkout/checkout.min.js" data-error="errorCallback"
    data-cancel="cancelCallback"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function errorCallback(error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
    function cancelCallback() {
        console.log('Payment cancelled');
    }
    Checkout.configure({
        merchant: 'X',
        order: {
            amount: function () {
                return 100;
            },
            currency: 'USD',
            description: 'Subscription Member',
            id: '1000',
        },
        interaction: {
            merchant: {
                name: 'Hsenid Mobile',
                address: {
                    line1: '200 Sample St',
                    line2: '1234 Example Town'
                }
            }
        },
        session: {
            id: "X"
        }
    });
</script>
```